# For Google Rich Snippets: Is it 'harmful' to add the same `hreview-aggregate` Microformat markup in several places?

Tags: seo, google-search, rich-snippets, page, microformats

We are right now incorporating [Microformats markup for reviews](http://microformats.org/wiki/hreview) into a client’s web application and were wondering, whether it can be harmful to provide the same information on more than one page, e.g., on a dynamic search page and on the concrete product page.

Does anybody have any experience with this?

**UPDATE:** Actually, I was wondering, if Google showed a link to the page the review comes from, then how would they decide which of the sources of the review they would link to? Or don’t they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you have an issue with this. It's common to have identical information on multiple pages in HTML so why not microformats as well? If that same information was in an HTML table then you would include it on both places, right? As long as each ID is unique and you're not trying to manipulate the system or creating duplicate content I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, John. I updated my question because I realised that I'm worried more about a potential conflict in **which source of the review** google would link to - since I have a **dedicated url** for every concrete review, even though it might appear elsewhere on the site.

Comment: Well, google will only show the rich snippet for a certain url, so as long as you resolve which url is canonical, it shouldn't be an issue, and in fact would be beneficial if a certain search term weights the results more heavily to an alternate page.